# return observable<void> inside another observable<object>

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, observable

I am new to `observables`, there is a parentMethod which returns `Observable<void>`,
in this method I have to call a childMethod which returns `Observable<responseObject>`, after I get responseObject I should post a http request and return `Observable<void>`, the calling and order of executing is important, something like below code which has syntax error. How should I think and how can I do this?

```
public childMethod(): Observable<someObject>{
    return //....
}
public parentMethod(): Observable<void> {
    return childMethod() // has error because it returns observable<someObject>
    .map((response)=>{
        return http.post(url, response as someobject) // I want to return this
    })
}
```

Comment: Is is a syntax or a type error?

Comment: What is the return type of `http.post`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the calling and order of executing is important*"? Which order do you want?

Comment: @Bergi, 1. sysntax type error, 2. `http.post` returns observable<void>, 3. first result of childMethod as observable and then post the result through `http.post`

Comment: You'll want to use `flatMap` then

Comment: @Bergi could you please give an example ??

Comment: I'm just writing the suggestion from @Bergi. 

    public childMethod(): Observable<someObject>{
        return //....
    } 
    public parentMethod(): Observable<void> {
        return childMethod() // has error because it returns observable<someObject>
            .flatMap((response)=>{
                return http.post(url, response as someobject) // I want to return this
            })
    }

Comment: @FabioCampinho you should answer it because writing code in comment is not good and readable, I find what should I do, but maybe other users can not find how to do this.

Comment: @Parid0kht, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just writing the suggestion from @Bergi.

```
public childMethod(): Observable<someObject>{
    return //....
} 
public parentMethod(): Observable<void> {
    return childMethod() // has error because it returns observable<someObject>
        .flatMap((response)=>{
            return http.post(url, response as someobject) // I want to return this
        })
}
```